# Can a web server detect a login from a script?

Tags: python, server, webserver

This might be a silly question. When use sessions with Python to request a file from a website behind a login, can the website detect that you are logging in via a script? How common is it for websites to detect this? I tried looking this up but couldn't find an answer so if this is a repeat question could you point me to some info so I can find my answer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the user agent. But other than that I don’t think its detectable.

You can change the user agent by setting a custom header e.g. `requests.get(url, headers= {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}`

Comment: Hey just had a question about updating this string to the latest version of chrome, should I just replace the "Chrome/60.0.3112.113" with the latest version number?
 
requests.get(url, headers= {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}

Comment: Yes it is possible you could change the string to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is  a silly question when you don't have the answer.

That being said, every request adds a header by default called the user agent, this can be a multitude of different things but is primarily used to detect what type of device or browser thenuser is connecting to the site with.

This includes Python requests! Python sends a user agent Python (version number) in its user agent header.

It is very common for webmasters to block these user agents, however, it is extremely simple to spoof the user agent header by changing it prior to sending the request itself.

You should look into header customisation of requests.

It is also very common for people writing scripts that connect to webserver to hide, spoof or otherwise obfuscate their user agent, but there are plenty more headers send by default which are also used to block unwanted traffic.

Hope this helps